# Why do plants produce so many hybrids as a kingdom?

Tags: evolution, botany

Why do plants produce so many hybrids? I have read that they are the largest kingdom of organisms to do so. Does this have something to do with polyploidy events?

Comment: [Might](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/935/why-is-polyploidy-lethal-for-some-organisms-while-for-others-is-not) be a bit related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it has very much to do with the poliploidy events. Specifically if you look at the grasses, most grasses that are diploid (eg., AA, BB), cannot hybridize, but in some rare events when they form polyploid (AAAA, BBBB), they can readily hybridize to form fertile progenies (AABB).

Comment: Do you have a citation for this claim?

Comment: I don't have the citation, but I recently attended a talk by [Dr. Kellogg](http://kellogglab.weebly.com/), who talked about this. I think her [paper](http://www.pnas.org/content/111/42/15149.abstract) talks about it briefly.

Comment: I found no evidence to your claims in the paper you linked. thus -1, I'll revoke if you can point me to it.